# Tumblr Pagination: How to make the “Previous Page” button go to the permalink of the "Previous Post"

Tags: pagination, tumblr, permalinks

I know this has already been asked here before, but I figured I'd give it a shot since none of the answers I have found online have worked when implemented.

I'm currently testing version 4 of the Simple Webcomic Theme (designed by Mr Geo Neo) on Tumblr for a webcomic that I write. I'm using a test Tumblr account while I edit the code of this theme, so that once finished, I can copy and past said code into the Tumblr used for the webcomic, and make just a few more changes.

I have set the test Tumblr so that you see 1 post per page. When on the homepage, you should see the most recent post, and then the "Previous" button. I want this button to link to the permalink of the previous post, not the next page of the blog.

There are many reasons I want this, one being that when posting new comics to social media, I use the permalink of the most recent comic/post. I also want to consolidate the Disqus comment sections on the website, so that there isn't two comments sections for every comic, one on the page and the other on the permalink.

If I can provide any more information regarding this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Permalink Pagination**

Tumblr provides theme operators for getting to the previous / next post when the user is on a permalink page:

```
{block:PermalinkPagination} 
    {block:PreviousPost}
        <a href="{PreviousPost}">Previous Post</a>
    {/block:PreviousPost}

    {block:NextPost}
        <a href="{NextPost}">Next Post</a>
    {/block:NextPost} 
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

However, based on the OP's requirement, this won't solve the issue. Its only rendered on a permalink page, not the index page.

AFAIK there is no sensible solution for the OP's requirement.